# tableViewCell accessory type issue in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, didselectrowatindexpath, uitableview, accessoryview

I have a tableView with list of persons. I want to select multiple cells. I've created a dictionary to store selected cells ([screenshot](http://oi58.tinypic.com/2u6zj1t.jpg)).

```
var checkedSubjects: [Person: Bool] = [Person: Bool]()
```

Then when I select a cell it shows a checkmark near the cell and save it in my array ([screenshot](http://oi61.tinypic.com/2nk0wmg.jpg)).

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: SearchTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SearchTableViewCell
    cell.tintColor = UIColor(hex: 0x3f51b5)
    cell.subjectNameLabel.text = subjects[indexPath.row].name
    cell.subjectDescriptionLabel.text = "(\(subjects[indexPath.row].type))"

    let person = Person(id: subjects[indexPath.row].id, name: subjects[indexPath.row].name, type: subjects[indexPath.row].type)
    if checkedSubjects[person] != nil {
        cell.accessoryType = checkedSubjects[person]! ? .Checkmark : .None
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
    let index = indexPath.row
    let person = Person(id: subjects[index].id, name: subjects[index].name, type: subjects[index].type)
    if tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!.accessoryType == .Checkmark {
        tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!.accessoryType = .None
        checkedSubjects[person] = false
        counter--
    } else {
        tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        checkedSubjects[person] = true
        counter++
    }
    if counter > 0 {
        saveBtn.enabled = true
        let text = counter == 1 ? "Add \(counter) person" : "Add \(counter) persons"
        saveBtn.setTitle(text, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    } else {
        saveBtn.enabled = false
        saveBtn.setTitle("Choose persons", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

But when I press this cell one more time I want it to return to default view. It removes checkmark but the text doesn't take empty space ([screenshot](http://oi58.tinypic.com/5cx0fd.jpg)). The trailing constraint of the label is set to container margin.

I've tried to `reloadData()` of tableView in didSelectRowAtIndexPath but it doesn't helped.

Any ideas how I can solve this issue?

Comment: @matt Thank you, I followed your answer and now it works well!)

Comment: Please post this as an answer and mark it as accpeted for proper housekeeping.

Comment: @matt It helped me, so let it be).

Comment: Okay, did so, and deleted my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you're trying to manipulate the physical cell in your `didSelectRow` implementation. This is the wrong way to go about things. Do not attempt to change or even read the accessory type of a cell in your `didSelectRow` implementation! Instead, operate there entirely on the model (`checkedSubjects`) and *reload* the affected row, so that the view picks up changes to the model (because `cellForRow` will be called).